# trouble with internet connection - slow to open web pages if they open at all until I put VPN on and then they open ok

Tags: internet, router, connection

I am having problems with my internet connection. At the moment I am on a mac and connected through a netgear wireless router. The internet connection either won't open a webpage at all or if it does it takes ages. However if I turn my VPN on the pages open at a normal speed. Also skype functions OK and I seem to be able to download files ok. I have tried connecting with a wire between the router and the computer and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your web browser has it's proxy set to a server behind your VPN.  If you're using Safari, see [here](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Safari/3.0/en/9299.html) for info on accessing that setting.